# What is the meaning of resistance?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, definition

I am a 10th grade student and I have a little trouble in knowing what is resistance?

I know this might be a silly question for others but My thinking of resistance is that it opposes the flow of charges/Current but I want to know that why the current remains the same even after passing through a resistance, If it is opposing the current , then it should get decreases, I know there is no charge storing device in between so the charges cannot be accumulate so, the current should remain same but then what's the point of resistance? If the charge flow is same everywhere why do we talk of resistance?

I mean suppose that if I have" i "amount of current going through two resistors separately one of them have resistance R and other at 2R ,do we mean that the charges will cross the resistance R in more time than 2R?But the rate of flow of charges inside the two resistors separately stays constant? But  I don't think so? because the current is same when it pass through both resistors separately so , same no. of charges will cross in same time so,I think that they will cross it in the same time.

please explain by giving as many examples as possible because its my first time I am reading about current and electricity so, I don't know much about it. I also don't think that the speed of current will decrease? suppose if  I have a less resistance does it mean that current will pass  through it in less time? I don't think so, I have that feel of resistance that it is opposing the flow and increasing the temperature, but I don't know the exact meaning of resistance?

Comment: Think of a resistor as a water filter or a constriction on the water hose. It makes it "tougher" for the water particles to pass through - nevertheless they all do pass through eventually, just fewer per second than otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In the [hydraulic analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy), resistance is like putting rocks in the pipe. It takes more effort (= pressure = voltage) to push water at high speed through rocks than through an empty pipe, even though the water leaves that section of pipe at the same rate that it enters whether the rocks are there or not.

Comment: @ Dr jh the electrons in the resistor are not slower , in the contrary the are faster thats why a resistor gets hot!

Comment: And because it take more effort, then for a *fixed* pressure the speed of the water *throughout the whole system* will be lower.